# how to add hooks after bundle update

Tags: node.js, webpack

EDIT:I need to directly generate `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>` format to a text file which my web app(django or rails) template engine can directly include. So a json file seems not ok.

After webpack update the js file in `webpack --progress --colors --watch` mode, I want to :

1. Create a copy with hashed-filename to specified path.
2. execute some nodejs code that lists all filenames in specified directory and writes them to a text file.

Currently my config file is:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }, 
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]}, 
        ], 

    }
};
```

For example, every time webpack generate a `bundle.[hash].js` file, it will first make its copy to `/bar`, then check all filenames in `/bar` and write these filenames to `/foo/bar/js.txt` in this format:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bar/bundle.sdfklsld.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bar/bundle.jkljsdfd.js"></script>
```

I know this maybe done by [bundle-update](https://github.com/skleeschulte/webpack-bundle-update-hook-plugin), but it's poorly documented.

Comment: Do django or rails have problems with reading `.json` files?

Comment: @Everettss but that would require another watching process who watches the json file and convert it to a text file every time it changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`assets-webpack-plugin`**](https://github.com/kossnocorp/assets-webpack-plugin) will be solution for you.

Your `webpack.config.js` with this plugin should look something like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const assetsPluginInstance = new AssetsPlugin({
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'foo', 'bar'),
    filename: 'js.json'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bar'),
        filename: "bundle.[hash].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }, 
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]}, 
        ], 

    },
    plugins: [
        assetsPluginInstance
    ]
};
```

Now in path `bar/` you should have file `bundle.sdfklsld.js`.
In file `foo/bar/js.json` you will have:

```
{
    "main": {
        "js": "/bar/bundle.sdfklsld.js"
    }
}
```

From that point you are good to go and create your script tags with proper path to bundle files.

#### Edit - create file `.txt` with script tags

If you want to create your assets as a plain text file you can use `processOutput` method in `assets-webpack-plugin`.

```
const assetsPluginInstance = new AssetsPlugin({
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'foo', 'bar'),
    filename: 'js.txt',  // change to .txt

    // it can be little different in your scenario 
    // - currently I'm showing only one file, 
    // but you can tweak it to accept array of files
    processOutput: function (assets) {
        return `<script type="text/javascript" src="${assets.main.js}"></script>`;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand this, maybe you can help? So if I wanted to include a file based on Json file that was generated, say `foo.adfeadf.js`, how would you include this in the HTML?

Comment: Take a look on this plugins: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin or https://github.com/szrenwei/inline-manifest-webpack-plugin