# Firebase Hosting: cache busting scripts on deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a Polymer (single page app) application hosted on firebase. When I deploy a new version to firebase, I'll like firebase to reload the javascript source instead of using cached ones. Is it possible to do that via firebase.json? If so, how? Or do i have to manually add a cache busting url to my build output? Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Adding Webpack or a similar tool to your build is probably the easiest way to go, as there's not currently a way to achieve the desired result with Firebase directly:

[How Can I Make Webpack Use a Cache-Busting Suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238163/how-can-i-make-webpack-use-a-cache-busting-suffix)

If you're okay removing the cache completely, you can simply set the related headers for the files you don't want cached in `firebase.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "headers": [{
      "source": "build.js",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "max-age=0"
      }]
  }],
  ...
}
```

See here for more details: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

Comment: but this would fetch build.js on every browser reload. I'd actually prefer if it only fetches once until the next deployment of a new version.

Comment: @user3240644 - That's true. I'm not sure it's possible using only `firebase.json`. Most people end up solving this via Webpack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238163/how-can-i-make-webpack-use-a-cache-busting-suffix

Comment: I would suggest removing the `firebase.json` part (or at least move it below the cache busting part) because it doesn't answer the question at all. OP explicitly mentioned "cache busting".

Comment: This answer although upvoted, doesn't actually contain an answer to the question apart from "webpack, webpack".

Comment: @Ashnur - Life is richer when one turns lemons into lemonade.

Comment: @TMan no question about it, but I still don't know what the answer is for firebase. Especially since I do not wish to use webpack.