# React + Firebase deploy needs a cache clear

Tags: reactjs, firebase, caching

I just deployed a very basic react application that I created using [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and then I built the app and deployed it through the Firebase CLI. When I changed something in the app and then built and deployed it again, I couldn't see the changes on the website when I refreshed the page. After some troubleshooting I figured out that this a cache issue and the browser just uses the older version of the file instead of reloading the new one. Which made sense because when I cleared the cache (or opened the window in incognito mode) I saw the changes I made.

My question is how would this work in a real world application? You can't expect or depend on the users to clear their cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered here [Firebase Hosting: cache busting scripts on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711466/firebase-hosting-cache-busting-scripts-on-deploy) You need to set the cache headers in firebase.json