# Date variable in JS import file name

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have small Vue app without Node.js and I import several component files.

I need to be sure that users will always get newest version of certain files/components, because I do some updates continuously.

My code is like this:

```
import InputComponent from './folder/editor-input.js';
import ProductComponent from './folder/editor-product.js';
..and so on
```

inside

`<script type="module"></script>`

I have tried two following ways and neither one worked.

```
const dateNow = Date.now(); 
import InputComponent from './moduly/editor-input.js?v='+dateNow;
```

and

```
const dateNow = Date.now(); 
import InputComponent from './moduly/editor-input.js?v={$dateNow}';
```

I want to have result like this:
`import InputComponent from './folder/editor-input.js?v=1691592140153';`

Is it even possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

Comment: Incorrect quotes for [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), as well as syntax: `${...}` not `{$...}`.

Comment: Not sure this is going to be useful at all, as these `import` operations are usually "packed" into your assets during a build. If you want to keep it up to date, build and deploy on a regular schedule. You'll also run into trouble if this is a local import as the filename won't have the `?v=...` stuff in it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this manually, the build process takes care of it for you.  I was pretty sure the usual Vue build process has this by default, but if not it's fairly straightforward webpack config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238163/how-to-use-cache-busting-with-webpack

Answer (score 3):

Static imports cannot depend on any value computed at runtime.

You'd need to use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) instead.

```js
const dateNow = Date.now(); 
const InputComponent = await import(`./moduly/editor-input.js?v=${dateNow}`;
```

(Note also the corrected syntax for the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

---

That said, using cache busting like this in a Vue app strikes me as unusual. My experience is mostly focused on React, but as far as I know they are usually built in similar ways.

Your JS files are bundled up at build time and then deployed.

The trick there is to leave your **source code alone** and configure your bundler to generate unique file names. e.g. with webpack you would set [the output filename](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename) to include a *hash*.